# Variable height UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

Im embedding a text view inside a table view cell. This text view is meant for writing long text.

How do it get a variable height uitextview that expands automatically when the entered text exceeds the assigned height of the uitextview. It must work like composing a message in the Mail app.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015557/uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell-smooth-auto-resize-shows-and-hides-keyboard-on-i). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set and implement delegate of `UITextView` delegate protocol
2. Check size of `UITextView.contentSize`. If it's height parameter has changed then you should expand table view cell:
   2.1 Reload particular cell.
   2.2 Return new height value in `UITableViewDelegate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281467/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height).

You can take the `font` property from `UITextView` to use in the `sizeWithFont:` method.

You should implement the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and every time the text view changes, that is, when `– textViewDidChange:` gets called you should reload the cell to adjust it to the content's size.

To reload a specific row, you can use `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this via Storyboard using the Content Hugging Priority property.

In IB I set the Text View height to a default value and gave this a priority of 250 (Low).

Text View Height[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b12LT.png)

I then set the Content Hugging Priority to 1000. The view resized to fit the text exactly I wanted.
Content Hugging Priority[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjZ8H.png)

Hope this helps